# How to print All zeros in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, c99

I want to print all the zeros in the input using this code.
for example:

```
 input: 10000 -------------- output: 0000
```

but I get this:

```
 input: 10000 -------------- output: 0
```

this is the source code in `C99`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {

  int co = 0, inputNumber, i, j, prod = 1, number = 0, ten = 10, newValue;
  int numberOfInputs;
  scanf("%d", &numberOfInputs);

  for(i = 1; i <= numberOfInputs; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &inputNumber);

    for(j = 1; j < inputNumber; j++) {
      if(inputNumber % j == 0) {
        prod = prod * j;
      }
    }
    if(prod < 10000)
      printf("%d", prod);

    else {
      newValue = prod;
      while((int)prod / 10 != 0) {
        prod = (int) prod/10;
        co++;
        number = newValue % ten;
        ten *= 10;
        if(co == 4) {
          printf("%d \n", number);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Please some help guys :)

Comment: `scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=1;i<=t;i++){
        scanf("%d",&n);` Is your input actually just `10000`?

Comment: I would advise against using "new" as a variable name. also get rid of your unnecessary casts. add some comments to your code. what is t? what is n?

Comment: Read it as a string and print a 0 for every 0 character in it.  This is too complicated.

Comment: The break is terminating your loop after what appears to be printing only 1 digit of your number.

Comment: Nope you aren't printing any digits until co=4.  You basically are skipping over all the digits until the 4th one.  Move the printf outside of the if(co==4)

Comment: And remove the \n from the printf

Comment: @Ben: no, actually I get the correct answer from all results, except for 10000, I just get 0 while I need 4 zeros.

Comment: What exactly is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @Dmitri this code supposed to calculate the product of a given number   -inputNumber- and print only its 4 first digits

Comment: Then why not do something like: printf("%04d", number % 10000) ?

Comment: @Knox Root When you say "first four digits",, do you want the right-most 4 digits?

Comment: it is much neater to take in the input as characters. I left you an answer that shows how this is done

Comment: @KnoxRoot: When you say, "the product of a given number -inputNumber-", do you mean you're trying to multiply all the *divisors* of that input value together?  Because that's what you're doing...

Comment: @JohnBode Yes-Except the inputNumber which won't be multiplied.

Comment: @KnoxRoot: Okay, and you want to print the 4 *low-order* digits of that product?  If so, then `printf( "%04d\n", prod % 10000);` should do it, I think...

Comment: @JohnBode Thank you ;) this would be the best solution.

Comment: @ForeverStudent: There's no problem using `new` as a variable name in C.  (It's a keyword in C++, but that's a different language.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I didn't say the variable name is illegal. I said I advise against getting in the habit of using "new" as a variable name. not every legal variable name is a good one .

Comment: @ForeverStudent: OK, *why" is `new` a bad variable name?

Comment: @KeithThompson because no programmer worth his salt will be programming only in C for the rest of his/her life. a little advice about how to choose smarter variable names will save his/her bacon one day

Comment: @ForeverStudent: Thank you for explaining the rationale for your warning. I completely disagree with it. There's nothing wrong with using `new` as an identifier *in C* -- or `class`, or `private`, or `DIVISION`, or `program`, or ``loop` (the last three are keywords in Cobol, Pascal, and Ada, respectively). If you're programming in C, program in C. If you're going to learn a new language, keywords are perhaps the most trivial part of the learning process. (In some cases it can make sense to write C that can also be compiled as C++, but the need for that is rare.)

Comment: Sorry, but `program` is not a reserved word in Ada.  In Ada the reserved word is `procedure` (and `is` also)  But you are right.... as being such the case, don't use `condition` as a boolean variable because it is something I do use for another purpose in my programs and doing so, your programming style will be conflicting with mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, you want to print out the four lowest-order digits of the product with leading zeros, which is pretty simple:

```
printf( "%04d\n", prod % 10000 );
```

Cleaning up and reformatting your code a bit basically reduces to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  int inputNumber, i, j, prod=1;
  int numberOfInputs;

  scanf( "%d", &numberOfInputs );
  for(i = 1; i <= numberOfInputs; i++ )
  {
    scanf("%d", &inputNumber);
    for(j = 1; j < inputNumber; j++ )
    {
      if( inputNumber % j == 0)
      {
        prod = prod*j;
      }
    }

    printf( "%04d\n", prod % 10000 );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a completely different approach, you can do this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    int zeroCounter=0;
    char inputNumber[256];
    printf("Please enter the numerical value:");

      fgets(inputNumber,256, stdin);
        int j;
        for(j=0; inputNumber[j]!='\n'; j++)
        {
            if(inputNumber[j]=='0') zeroCounter++;
        }

        printf("this value had %d zeros, here they are:    ",zeroCounter);

        while(zeroCounter!=0)
        {
            printf("0");
            zeroCounter--;
        }
        printf("\n");
return 0;
}
```

what this code does is it sniffs the character array you input, and counts the 0 characters. then it can print them if required. no division and bitshifting shenanigans required.

Comment: Safer to use `for(j=0; inputNumber[j]; j++)`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, can you elaborate please

Comment: With select input (like 255 digits), `inputNumber[]` may not have a `'\n'` in it. and the `for` loop goes off in to [la-la land](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Lalaland).  As a _string_, code can count on `inputNumber[]` having a `'\0'`, (unless `fgets()` returned `NULL`)

Answer (score 1):

Well your current problems are that because of the overflows, `prod` ends to be 0. And as `0 < 10000` you just pass through the single print: `if(prod<10000)printf("%d",prod);` just bypassing all your complex printing code.
In fact it overflows (to a negative value) at least at for a value as small as 84.

But that's not all. Even if `prod` does not overflow, you compute a number of at most 4 digits in `number` but print if in `%d` format. If number is less than 1000, you will not print the highest order 0 with that format, but you should use `%04d`.

Here is a minimally fixed version:

```
int main(){


    int co=0,inputNumber,i,j,prod=1,number=0,ten=10,newValue;
    int numberOfInputs;
    scanf("%d",&numberOfInputs);
    for(i=1;i<=numberOfInputs;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&inputNumber);
        prod = 1; /* reset prod */
        for(j=1;j<inputNumber;j++) {
            if(inputNumber%j==0) {
                prod = prod*j;
                if (prod <= 0) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (prod <=0) {
            printf("Overflow\n");
        }
        else if(prod<10000) {
            printf("%04d\n",prod);
        }

        else
        {
            newValue = prod;
            while((int)prod/10 != 0)
            {
                prod = (int)prod/10;
                co++;
                number = newValue%ten;
                ten*=10;
                if(co==4)
                {
                    printf("%04d \n",number);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But in fact the `else` part should just be:

```
        else
        {
            printf("%04d \n",prod % 10000);
        }
```